# Open a quick link with a specific browser?

Tags: url

Is there a way in SharePoint Online to open a URL with a specfic browser? We have a case whereby certain URL should open with Internet explorer instead of the default browser Chrome; Any advise is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut like this:

"**C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://servername/**

Then, you can call this from Java script like below :

```
<a href="example.com"> you have <a href="my-shortcut.lnk">
```

For details refer to the below article :

[Force a link on a web server to open in Internet Explorer](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1916591-force-a-link-on-a-web-server-to-open-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Chrome policies for legacy browser redirection. You can find out how to set that up at [Legacy Browser Support (integrated) for Windows](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9270076).

You won't be able to have a shortcut on a page (`a href`) that launches another application, that would cross the security boundary in place.